# Rewrite Website Links (Anchors, Extensions)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have several pages on my website where the home page contains some anchors links like this:

- mywebsite.com/homepage.php#six

  and other pages just PHP extensions like this:
- mywebsite.com/otherpage.php

What shall I do if I want to remove everything after slash on home page and the PHP extension on others?

Comment: do you use php or other technology on these pages? Why don't you just remove them from the source code?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want with examples (before  and after) and what you want to happen. What have you tried so far, and where did you bump into problems?

Comment: @koenpeters I user some PHP. To include other pages for example of to send forms. How can I remove them from the source code?

Comment: @trincot as an example I need to change mywebsite.com/homepage.php#six to this mywebsite.com/ on homepage and mywebsite.com/otherpage.php to this mywebsite.com/otherpage/ on other pages. I did not try anything yet, just because I lost in the articles about htaccess and javascript solutions. Some says that I can't remove # with htaccess. I am not looking for ready scripts for this, just want to ask a direction do choose best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /homepage.php#six [NE,L]

#Remove php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite

```
http://example.com/
```

to

```
http://example.com/homepage.php#six
```

And the second rule removes php extensions from files.

Comment: do I need to use multiple line in case if I have several links with anchors? like this RewriteRule ^$ /homepage.php#one [NE,L] RewriteRule ^$ /homepage.php#two[NE,L]?

Comment: No, you cant point your hompage to multiple #links, And also you cant use multiple rewrite rule with same patterns ^$, But rewriting  a url like http://example.com/one  to  http://example.com/homepage.php#one is possible.

Comment: and there is no any rule to remove everything after example.com right? when I am on the page, and click anchors it's ok, nothing appears in the link, but when I am on an another page, and go back to my home page using the index.php#two of  index.php#three for example I get example.com/index.php#two in the address line

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /homepage\.php(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /homepage.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This code removes php extension but when I am on the "otherpage" and go back to home page where the link is index.php#two for example I get homepage.com/index#two

Comment: @EmilGurbanov That is because you want to hide the `homepage.php`.

Comment: in any case I can't get rid of the  anchors, even if I don't hide the homepage